# How do i stop both of my players from moving at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

// Here is the code i have so far below. Both of my balls are moving at the same time no matter which controls i use. can someone please lend me a helping hand?

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public float speed = 80.0f; // Code for how fast the ball can move. Also it will be public so we can change it inside of Unity itself. 
public GameObject player1; //Player 1 Rigidbody
public GameObject player2; //Player 2 Rigidbody
private Rigidbody rb;
private Rigidbody rb2;

void Start () 
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    rb2 = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    player1 = GameObject.Find("Player"); 
    player2 = GameObject.Find("Player 2");
}

//Player 1 Code with aswd keys
 void Player1Movement()
{
    if (player1 = GameObject.Find("Player")) 
    {

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
            rb.AddForce (Vector3.left * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
            rb.AddForce (Vector3.right * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
            rb.AddForce (Vector3.forward * speed);

        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
            rb.AddForce (Vector3.back * speed);

        }
    }
}

//Player 2 Code with arrow keys
void Player2Movement()
{
    if( player2 = GameObject.Find("Player 2"))
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        rb2.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed);

    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        rb2.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed);

    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        rb2.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);

    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        rb2.AddForce(Vector3.back * speed);

    }
}
```

}

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Player1Movement();
    Player2Movement();
}
```

}

How do i change it so both of my players aren't moving at the same time?

Comment: Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same rigidbody for both characters somehow. rb1 and 2 are the same rigidbody. You should use GameObject.Find or something like that to make rb2 the second players rigidbody.

Edit: you can use player2.GetComponent() to grab the second player's rigidbody. Assuming this script is attached to the first player

Answer (score 0):

For both Player1 and Player2 you are using the same transition code. You are displacing both at the same rate.
For difference in speed lets say you want to update player 2 at double speed on left arrow use `rb2.AddForce(Vector3.left *2* speed);`
Now if you want player to move only on some even then inside `Update()` enclose your Player movement inside mouse down or other events.
 You can use `RaycastHit` to check which GameObject was tapped and update that one only.